# How to install laravel parse with laravel 5.7.*?

Tags: laravel-5.7

I want to connect my Laravel 5.7.18 to parse server. But the problem is that Laravel-Parse supports Laravel 5.4 only.

I tried installing [Laravel-Parse](https://github.com/LaravelParse/Laravel-Parse), but it produces the following error:

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

It turns out the error occurs because of the Laravel version I am using (5.7.18)

How can I get this working?

Comment: You can’t. Either ask library maintainer for your laravel version support or don’t use it.

Comment: Already fixed. try this https://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/
Worked for me.